# Query to replace a string with matching pattern

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

I have a string like below.

**'comp' as "COMPUTER",'ms' as "MOUSE" ,'keybr' as "KEYBOARD",'MONT' as "MONITOR",**

Is it possible to write a query so that i will get the result as

**'comp' ,'ms' ,'keybr' ,'MONT' ,**

I can replace the string "as" with empty string using REPLACE query.
But how do I remove the string inside double quote?

Can anyone help me doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select replace(
               regexp_replace('''comp'' as "COMPUTER"'
                              , '(".*")'
                              ,null)
               ,' as '
               ,null)
from dual
```

The regex `'(".*")'` selects text whatever in double quotes.

EDIT:

the regex replaced the entire length of the matching pattern. So, we might need to tokenise the string first using comma as delimiter and apply the regex. Later join it.(`LISTAGG`)

```
WITH str_tab(str1, rn) AS
(SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL), -- delimts
        LEVEL 
   FROM (SELECT '''comp'' as "computer",''comp'' as "computer"' str
           FROM dual) tab
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REPLACE(str, ',')) + 1)
SELECT listagg(replace(
               regexp_replace(str1
                              , '(".*")'
                              ,null)
               ,' as '
               ,null), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn) AS new_text
  FROM str_tab;
```

EDIT2:

A [cleaner approach](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/31625) from @EatAPeach

```
with x(y) as (
  select q'<'comp' as "COMPUTER",'ms' as "MOUSE" ,'keybr' as "KEYBOARD",'MONT' as "MONITOR",>'
  from dual
)
select y,
       regexp_replace(y, 'as ".*?"' ,null)
from x;
```

Comment: I tried this way -  select replace(
               regexp_replace('''comp'' as "COMPUTER",''ms'' as "MOUSE" ,''keybr'' as "KEYBOARD",''MONT'' as "MONITOR",'
                              , '(".*")'
                              ,null)
               ,' as '
               ,null)
from dual

Comment: I get only this:   'comp',

Comment: Can u please help me out

Comment: @OracleUser, No need for tokenising and aggregating. You can use the non greedy quantifier, [.*?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/31625) in your first query.